# How to change to an older version of Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am running Node.js version `v0.5.9-pre` on Ubuntu 10.10.

I would like to be using version `v0.5.0-pre`.

How do I roll back to the older version of node?

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but if anyone is using [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/), check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula

Comment: If you want to just test your package in an older version, it's worth mentioning the `node` package, which you can install as a local executable. For example, v12.1: `npm i --no-save node@12.1`. You can run it on current folder like `./node_modules/node/bin/node .`. The downside is that you can't/shouldn't install it globally.

Comment: To use `nvm` on a Mac I had to follow these directions https://dev.to/duhbhavesh/nvm-command-not-found-1ho and https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating

Answer (score 654, accepted):

One way is to use NVM, the Node Version Manager.

Use following command to get nvm

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
```

You can find it at https://github.com/creationix/nvm

It allows you to easily install and manage multiple versions of node. Here's a snippet from the help:

```
Usage:
nvm install <version>       Download and install a <version>
nvm use <version>           Modify PATH to use <version>
nvm ls                      List versions (installed versions are blue)
```

Comment: After the server restarts, it unsets nvm and I have to tell it to start using a specific version again. Even after setting `nvm alias default v0.5.0` Would you happen to know how to get it to maintain the settings after a reboot?

Comment: This is what I did - from the docs: "To activate nvm, you need to source it from your bash shell . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
I always add this line to my ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile file to have it automatically sources upon login. Often I also put in a line to use a specific version of node."

Comment: this one did not work for me. Always seam to be on the same version. https://github.com/tj/n worked better for me, simpler.

Comment: Is there a close way to do this with NPM also? That is, to change npm package manager to a previous version of itself.

Comment: Also you can have `.nvmrc` file in directory with description of version you want to use. And then just make `nvm use` and don't care about anything

Comment: I tried nvm a lot and found it wasn't very intuitive.  Just tried *NIX below and was immediately able to install and switch versions without errors.

Comment: nvm doesn't support Windows, you may have to use nvm-windows for the same, you can see the repository here https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows.

Comment: While `nvm` (and `n`) are quite popular (and easy), it can quickly become troublesome switching between multiple projects that use different versions. Much easier to just add `node` as a dependency in `package.json` and let `npm` or `yarn` deal with picking the right one.

Comment: doesn't work on windows. you need to install with the other answer below, then use nvm

Comment: NVM is so broken though, it crashes all the time, especially with express servers.

Answer (score 804):

## *NIX (Linux, OS X, ...)

[Use **n**](https://github.com/tj/n), an extremely simple Node version manager that can be installed via npm.

Say you want Node.js v0.10.x to build [Atom](https://github.com/atom/atom).

```bash
npm install -g n   # Install n globally
n 0.10.33          # Install and use v0.10.33
```

```bash
Usage:
n                            # Output versions installed
n latest                     # Install or activate the latest node release
n stable                     # Install or activate the latest stable node release
n <version>                  # Install node <version>
n use <version> [args ...]   # Execute node <version> with [args ...]
n bin <version>              # Output bin path for <version>
n rm <version ...>           # Remove the given version(s)
n --latest                   # Output the latest node version available
n --stable                   # Output the latest stable node version available
n ls                         # Output the versions of node available
```

## Windows

Use [**nvm-windows**](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows), it's like [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) but for Windows. Download and run the [installer](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases), then:

```bash
nvm install v0.10.33         # Install v0.10.33
nvm use v0.10.33             # Use v0.10.33
```

```bash
Usage:
nvm install [version]        # Download and install [version]
nvm uninstall [version]      # Uninstall [version]
nvm use [version]            # Switch to use [version]
nvm list                     # List installed versions
```

Comment: nvm works fine for me on Windows, we are recommending it for all of our developers (testing npm 0.10 to 0.12 upgrade issues). Not sure if this answer is out of date, or incorrect.

Comment: @BobFields [nvm doesn't support Windows](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/tree/0d898b0aa478cf86ea7afb6a733e8d2ff6ae75dd#readme). Perhaps you're using [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)?

Comment: `n` is amazing. Typing $n and just arrows up and down then enter to select the version to use!

Comment: nvmw is no longer maintained

Comment: `n use vesion` Can't change a node version globally. Just one-time changed.

Comment: For those looking for some kind of version manager for a PC - I posted an alternative solution below.

Comment: [Nodist](https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist) is way better for windows. Super easy and quick to set up.

Comment: This answer should be edited to remove the Windows part, nvmw is no longer supported.  Any attempt to use it on Windows 10 yields "ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value."

Comment: Didn't work out of the box on Ubuntu. `n 9.6.0` claims it installed 9.6.0 but `node -v` still shows 9.6.1.

Comment: npm i -g nvmw installs the package but the term nvmw is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program. Tried this on W10 with no results

Comment: `n` is a bad idea, if you sometimes want to [remove `n` and its node versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49667391/183704) from your system.

Comment: I had to do some work on a very old web app written in AngularJS 1.5. I had no idea which node version would work, so I played around using `n`. It made the hole process very easy... Thanks!
Works perfectly on a Mac (High Sierra)

Comment: I had the biggest headache with nvm. This solution worked fantastic for me on Ubuntu 16.04. I am managing two different projects, one of which requires an old version of node to build. This solution makes it trivial to switch between node versions and build each project. Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I needed to do the following as well: Create a directory for n: `sudo mkdir /usr/local/n`; set permission: `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/n`

Comment: It is worth to notice that the last edit about the Windows part works like a charm. I could successfully manage my node version using nvm-windows.

Comment: _"*NIX (Linux, OSX, ...)"_ - but **not any BSD *NIX** - apparently it depends on prebuilt binaries hosted at the repo, but they don't build any BSD ones.

Comment: Please someone put this answer at the top, it's literally the only one that works on windows. Also, can people stop posting mac only or windows only answers?

Comment: `sudo n latest` worked for me after install for latest nodejs

Comment: I use "npm install -g n"
on Windows 10 using Ubuntu distro in WSL (windows subsystem for linux) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: This simply worked for me, windows 10. i had installed v14 but while setting up something it accidentally got upgraded to v16 which prevented me from completed an azure learning path exercise. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/automatic-update-of-a-webapp-using-azure-functions-and-signalr/3-exercise-analyze-limitations-of-polling-in-a-web-app

nvm install 14
nvm use 14.0.0 worked

Comment: Wonderful library!

Comment: `npm install -g n` didn't work for me on OSX, I got "command not found". But `brew install n` worked.

Comment: This is an anti-pattern. `n` is wonderful for quick and dirty checks but you should stay away from it (and `nvm`) if you're going to come back to a project. Sure it's quick enough and easy to understand but it is fundamentally broken when you have multiple versions in concurrent use/development. Just let Npm handle it for you and you can stop thinking about versions.

Comment: Important note: `nvmw` and `nvm-windows` are two different applications, both providing nvm-like functionality in Windows.  While `nvmw` is no longer maintained, [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) is still supported.  I haven't used it a lot but from what I've seen so far it works.

Answer (score 186):

**Update: Updated the answer because previous one was not relevant.**

Follow below steps to update your node version.

**1. Install nvm** For this run below command in your terminal

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
```

Note: If above command did not work for you, you can choose another option to install it. I have added an answer for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70232818/9266400)

**2. Install specific node version using nvm**

For this run

Replace `12.14.1` with your node version

```
nvm install 12.14.1
```

*Note: If you are getting error of NVM not recognised then run below command and then run above again*

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

**3. Make the installed version default**

*Note: Replace 12.14.1 with your installed version.*

```
nvm alias default 12.14.1
```

and

```
nvm use 12.14.1
```

**4. Check node version**

```
node -v
```

And that's it.

**Extra**

To check list of installed node versions -- run below command

```
nvm ls
```

Comment: Frustratingly, this does not change my node version.

Comment: I tried this approach and it didnt work. What did work was to uninstall the node package from the "add or remove programs" snappin. Then, download the desired version from the node website.

Comment: I'm on a mac and in my case I didn't need to add `sudo`, so just typing `npm install -g node@8.12.0` worked fine

Comment: Thanks a lot! This approach helps to install node@10.17.0 to my project, and then let me succeed on installing Realm@3.4.0. Before that, I've retried many different approaches but still failed on installing the latest Realm on my Windows for my React-Native project.

Comment: I have updated the answer this should work

Comment: As an FYI to future frustrated people: My node -v kept showing my old version after I updated. I reopened the console and it was right.

Comment: This didn't work for me; how do I remove?

Comment: `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`
this not working at my side with 'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @junnyea you will have to activate it. can you check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921188/issue-with-virtualenv-cannot-activate

Comment: Worked for me in Oct 2021.

Comment: This is an anti-pattern. `nvm` is wonderful for quick and dirty checks but you should stay away from it (and `n`) if you're going to come back to a project. Sure it's quick enough and easy to understand but it is fundamentally broken when you have multiple versions in concurrent use/development. Just let Npm handle it for you and you can stop thinking about versions.

Answer (score 99):

Why use any extension when you can do this without extension :)

**Install specific version of node**

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Specific version : `sudo n 4.4.4` instead of `sudo n stable`

Comment: Apparently `n` is not supported on windows.

Comment: on ubuntu ,the following error is casted:npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.

Comment: @HarlanChen It is not an error. It's a warning. You can ignore it.

Comment: Isn't `n` an extension? When you do `npm install -g n` you are installing an extension...

Comment: pls ignore the `sudo` part. you shouldn't do this

Comment: @kreig303 what do you suggest we do instead? Running it without sudo gives an error "cannot create directory '/usr/local/n': permission denied". Should we chmod that directory instead?

Answer (score 44):

## With `package.json` - The Maintainable and Portable Way

#### *Lets each project specify its own version*

You can add `node` as a dependency in `package.json` and control which version is used for a particular project. Upon executing a `package.json` "script", `npm` (and `yarn`) will use that version to run the script instead of the globally installed Node.js.

The `node` package accomplishes this by downloading a `node` binary for your local system and puts it into the `node_modules/.bin` directory.

You can also do this with the `npm` (or `yarn`) packages but you'll need to set your `PATH` up specifically or use something like `npx` that handles it for you.

---

## Ubuntu - The Official Way (manually)

If you're on node 12 and want to downgrade to node 10, just remove node and follow the instructions for the desired version:

```sh
# Remove the version that is currently installed
sudo apt remove -y nodejs

# Setup sources for the version you want
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -

# (Re-)Install Node
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

---

## Windows - The Official Way (manually)

I found myself wanting to downgrade to LTS on Windows from the bleeding edge. If you're not using a package manager like Chocolatey or a node version manager like `nvm` or `n`, just download the `.msi` for the version you want and install it. You might want to remove the currently installed version via "Add or remove programs" tool in Windows.

### Windows Package Manager - [`winget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/)

[The Open Source Windows Package Manager Way](https://winget.run/pkg/OpenJS/Nodejs)

```
winget install -e --id OpenJS.Nodejs -v 14.9.0
```

### Chocolatey - The Independent Package Manager Way

Chocolatey is good for keeping installations up to date easily and it is a common way to install Node.js on Windows. I had to remove the bleeding edge version before installing the LTS version:

```
choco uninstall nodejs

choco install nodejs-lts
```

---

## Node Version Manager - The "Screw it, I'll do it myself!" Way

While not very portable or easily maintainable, some developers like manually switching which global version of node is active at any given point in time and think the official ways of doing this are too slow. There are two popular Npm packages that provide helpful CLI interfaces for selecting (and automatically installing) whichever version you want for your system: [`nvm`](https://nvm.sh) and [`n`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n). Using either is beyond the scope of this answer.

I **highly recommend** staying away from this option. Even though it's popular, it's an anti-pattern that is sure to cause headaches in the future. Sure, `.nvmrc` exists, but this is reinventing something that's already a part of Npm. Just `npm i node` the version you want.

Comment: I've never thought of putting `node` as (dev) dependency, that's brilliant! You just need `npm` to be able to install it. What if you're using node 10.x and use node 14.x as dependency and need to install a package that needs to build binaries, e.g. `node-sass`? I guess this is a downside of this approach, right?

Comment: @SilviuBurcea In fact it's the opposite (or should be)! It will use the one you specify! Let's say you have a modern version of Node installed globally on your system, with up to date Npm. If you put some old version of Node in the `dependencies`, when starting a `package.json#script` with `npm run ...` or `yarn ...`, the local (old) Node will be put on the `PATH`, and it will *run* in the **old** Node version! This way, new versions of Node, that normally break old packages, don't.

Comment: your tip for package.json doesn't work, it doesn't install node inside node_modules/.bin

Comment: @danilo I think something went wrong on your end. I just tried it (`mkdir test; cd test; npm init -y; npm i --save node`) and now I have a `node` binary at `node_modules/.bin/node`.

Comment: @CameronTacklind, thank you very very much, it worked!

Answer (score 17):

## Windows

#### Downgrade Node with Chocolately

[Install Chocolatey.](https://chocolatey.org/) Then run:

```
choco install nodejs.install -version 6.3.0
```

Chocolatey has [lots of Node versions available](https://chocolatey.org/packages/nodejs.install).

#### Downgrade NPM

```
npm install -g npm@3.10.3
```

Comment: and for linux? :)

Comment: @noob-fella It's probably available via apt-get; I have not tried it.

Comment: can you switch between different Node.js versions on-the-fly with Chocolately?

Comment: You'll need to add the `--alow-downgrade` option like this: `choco install nodejs.install -version 6.3.0 --allow-downgrade`

Answer (score 16):

the easiest way i have found is to just **use the nodejs.org** site:

1. go to https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/
2. find version you want and click download
3. on mac click the **.pkg** executable and follow the installation instructions (not sure what the correct executable is for windows)
4. be happy now that you are on the version of node you wanted

Comment: on Windows: the msi won't downgrade a node version. It just plain exits.

Comment: @Bernard did you try to remove the undesired version with Windows's "Add or Remove Programs" feature?

Comment: I finally uninstalled it from various ways until no more signs of nodejs in the system. Then I used nvm and it worked to switch to any nodejs version at will.

Answer (score 11):

You need to install NVM for this.

**For Mac**

Edit `.bash_profile` using the below command.

```
nano .bash_profile
```

And add the following lines to  `.bash_profile`

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

> Save it. Exit the terminal and check the magic.

Then install the required version using the below command.

```
nvm install v14.18.0
```

If you want to check the installed node versions on your system. Use the below command.

```
nvm ls
```

If you want to use the specific version from the installed node versions. Use below command

```
nvm use 12.14.4
```

Answer (score 10):

nvmw is no longer maintained, but I found another source that seems to be up to date (as of 1/4/17).

[nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

It works.  Allowed me to downgrade to 6.3.1

Answer (score 7):

Another good library for managing multiple versions of Node is N: https://github.com/visionmedia/n

Answer (score 7):

I faced a lot of issue with this and the only solution that worked for me is:

```html
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

nvm install v[node_version]

nvm use v[node_version]
```

- You can type `nvm ls-remote` to browse available versions.
- Example: `nvm install v14.21.3`

Comment: As of March 11, 2023, It solved my problem! (My MacOS version is 10.13.6.)

Answer (score 6):

On windows 7 I used the general 'Uninstall Node.js' (just started typing in the search bottom left ,main menu field) followed by clicking the link to the older version which complies with the project, for instance:
Windows 64-bit Installer: https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.4.6/node-v4.4.6-x64.msi

Answer (score 5):

I had node version 6.4.0 .

As i am need of the older version 6.3.0 , i just installed the 6.3.0 version again in my system. node version downgraded automatically.

So, to downgrade the node version ,
Just install the older version of node js . It will get downgraded automatically from the higher version.

I tried in osx . It works like a charm .

Answer (score 3):

Now the `v0.5.0-pre` has reached end of life. We can use `npx` to use any stable older version of node. E.g. the earliest stable version is `4.9.0`.

```
npx -p node@4.9.0 -- node -v
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason Brew installs node 5 into a separate directory called node5.

The steps I took to get back to version 5 were: (You will need to look up standard brew installation/uninstallation, but otherwise this process is more straightforward than it looks.)

1. Install node5 using Brew standard installation, BUT don't brew link, yet.
2. Uninstall all other versions of node using brew unlink node and brew uninstall node. You might need to use --force to remove one of the versions.
3. Find the cellar folder on your computer
4. Delete the node folder in the cellar.
5. Rename the node5 folder to node.
6. Then, brew link node

You should be all set with node 5.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way i found -

1. Uninstall current version
2. Download the appropriate .msi installer (x64 or x86) for the desired version from https://nodejs.org/download/release/

Answer (score 2):

**Use following commnad with your version number**

```
nvm install v8.9
nvm alias default  v8.9
nvm use v8.9
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are like, you already install node version you want but can't seem to switch to it, try this:

1. `nvm use --delete-prefix <version>`. npm shows the lates version installed but can't switch to it. If so, this is the output you will see:

   `You need to run "nvm install v16.2.0`
2. Then run:`nvm install <type the version you wish to use here>`Your output should look like this:
   `Downloading and installing node v16.2.0... Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.2.0/node-v16.2.0-linux-x64.tar.xz... ####################################################################### 100.0% Computing checksum with sha256sum Checksums matched! Now using node v16.2.0 (npm v7.13.0) Creating default alias: default -> v16.2.0`
3. You are done! You can see the latest version by running:
   `node -v`

Answer (score 2):

This fix my problem

install new version node with nvm command
nvm install v16.19.1

change current version node
nvm use v16.19.1

check if the version is changed
node -v

Answer (score 1):

run this:

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clear && npm install
```

Node will install from whatever is cached. So if you clear everything out first, then NPM use 0.10.xx, it will revert properly.

Comment: This is not answering the OP's question. This is a manual way to remove npm dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

`nvm install 0.5.0` #install previous version of choice

`nvm alias default 0.5.0` #set it to default

`nvm use default` #use the new default as active version globally.

Without the last, the active version doesn't change to the new default. So, when you open a new terminal or restart server, the old default version remains active.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to go to the LTS version of node which is the stable one from the latest/current version simply run this in your directory.

> npm i node

this will install the LTS version of node in your directory.

Answer (score 1):

The Easiest way I find to install `node.js` with a specific version:

1. First uninstall your `node.js`
2. Go to, https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/ and find your desired version.

[image]

3. Select your version and click on the download button.
4. Download `.msi` file

Answer (score 0):

follow the steps if u already install curl its work for me

1. sudo snap remove curl
2. sudo apt install curl
3. nvm install 12.2.0

Answer (score 0):

As i can see this was asked a long time ago, but maybe it can be helpful for someone else.
I can recommend this utility (NVS - Node Version Switcher) to someone who is searching for a way to switching between different versions of NodeJS:

***https://github.com/jasongin/nvs***