# Issue with virtualenv - cannot activate

Tags: python, virtualenv

I created a virtualenv around my project, but when I try to activate it I cannot.
It might just be syntax or folder location, but I am stumped right now.

You can see below, I create the virtualenv and call it venv. Everything looks good, then I try to activate it by running `source venv/bin/activate`

I'm thinking it might just have to do with my system path, but not sure what to point it to (I do know how to edit the path). I'm on python 7 / windows os, virtual env 2.2.x

```
Processing dependencies for virtualenv
Finished processing dependencies for virtualenv

c:\testdjangoproj\mysite>virtualenv --no-site-packages venv
The --no-site-packages flag is deprecated; it is now the default behavior.
Using real prefix 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python'
New python executable in venv\Scripts\python.exe
File venv\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg exists with different content; not overwri
ting
Installing setuptools.................done.
Installing pip...................done.

c:\testdjangoproj\mysite>source venv/bin/activate
'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

c:\testdjangoproj\mysite>source venv/bin/activate
'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

c:\testdjangoproj\mysite>source mysite/bin/activate
'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

c:\testdjangoproj\mysite>
```

Comment: This documentation really helps out for both Posix and Windows systems: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/

Comment: Source command will not run in windows environment.

Answer (score 585, accepted):

`source` is a shell command designed for users running on Linux (or any Posix, but whatever, not Windows).

On Windows, virtualenv creates a .bat/.ps1 file, so you should run `venv\Scripts\activate` instead (per the virtualenv [documentation on the activate script](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/legacy/userguide.html#activate-script)).

Just run `activate`, without an extension, so the right file will get used regardless of whether you're using cmd.exe or PowerShell.

Comment: This also helps with `virtualenv` on both Posix and Windoze systems. https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/

Comment: I don't see this "venv" directory after installing Python 2.7 on Windows. Advice? I went to Blairg23's link, but do not see an "activate" script in my Python "Scripts" directory.

Comment: or just `activate`

Comment: i ran `.\\venv\Scripts\activate.bat` but the command just passes on windows 10 without actiavting venv sysmbol **(venv) C:\myApp**. what is the problem

Comment: I ran `. venv\scripts\activate` On Vscode PowerShell Extension and it worked fine.

Comment: In order to run a bat file in windows, enter full path without . like:
"C:\full-path-to-file\activate.bat"

Comment: Okay so suppose I created a venv in linux machine and then try to run it in windows. How will I do that?

Comment: The documentation hyperlink no longer works.

Comment: I did this but getting error when running pip install inside venv. `No python at "path" `

Comment: reason for me was running with ".bat"

Comment: '.venv\Scripts\activate.bat' seems to be the most reliable option on windows.

Comment: Please note if you are using vs code ensure you using cmd terminal. Windows shell happens not to work with this.

Answer (score 60):

I had the same problem. I was using Python 2, Windows 10 and Git Bash. Turns out in Git Bash you need to use:

```
 source venv/Scripts/activate
```

Comment: I have a Windows computer and using the Git Bash terminal was the only terminal that worked for me. (The other terminals I tried to use was Command Prompt and the VS Code terminal.)

Comment: I used it the same way with Python 3.10, Windows 10, and Git Bash.

Answer (score 43):

I was also facing the same issue in my Windows 10 machine.
What steps i tried were:

Go to andconda terminal
Step 1

```
pip3 install -U pip virtualenv
```

Step 2

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python ./venv
```

or

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./venv
```

Step 3

```
.\venv\activate
```

You can check it via spider tool in anaconda by typing `import tensorflow as tf`

Comment: I keep forgetting that I can't use forward slashes in the command prompt.

Comment: that worked! i just shocked that so many solutions and none of them do the right thing!
ALSO!!! After:
 virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python ./venv

You need: venv\Scripts\activate
look at the accepted solution somewhere below

Answer (score 36):

1. For activation you can go to the `venv` your virtualenv directory
   by `cd venv`.
2. Then on Windows, type `dir` (on unix, type `ls`). 
   You will get 5 folders `include`, `Lib`, `Scripts`, `tcl` and 60
3. Now type `.\Scripts\activate` to activate your virtualenv `venv`.

Your prompt will change to indicate that you are now operating within the virtual environment. It will look something like this `(venv)user@host:~/venv$`.

And your `venv` is activated now.

Comment: In Windows10 `.\Scripts\activate`

Answer (score 19):

**source** command is officially for **Unix** operating systems family and you can't use it on windows basically. instead, you can use **`venv\Scripts\activate`** command to activate your virtual environment.

[image: Made a Screenshot of how venv\Scripts\activate command works correctly]

Answer (score 12):

Ensure venv is there  and just follow the commands below. It works in Windows 10.

Go to the path where you want your virtual enviroments to reside:

```
> cd <my_venv_path>
```

Create the virtual environment named "env":

```
> python -m venv env
```

Add the path to the git ignore file (optional):

```
> echo env/ >> .gitignore
```

Activate the virtual env:

```
> .\env\Scripts\activate
```

Comment: This was right on!

Answer (score 9):

As of python 3.3 `virtualenv` became part of python under the name `venv` you can read more on it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

*Note: if you're on ubuntu you need to do a bit of [extra work](https://www.arubacloud.com/tutorial/how-to-create-a-python-virtual-environment-on-ubuntu.aspx)*

to create a virtual environment you simply do:

```
python -m venv env
```

in this case i named it "env" but it can be whatever you want

now to activate it it differs a bit so i'll start with the easiest

**linux:**

```
source ./env/bin/Activate
```

**windows:**

if you're using cmd then:

```
.\env\Scripts\activate.bat
```

**if you're using powershell** (default for vscode), then you need to do a bit more work

first you need to enable "running scripts" on your system (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18713789/12429279))

you can do that with this (as admin):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

then you can activate your venv with

```
.\env\Scripts\activate.ps1
```

Answer (score 6):

Tried several different commands until I came across:

```
source venv/Scripts/activate
```

This did it for me.  Setup: Win 10, python 3.7, gitbash.  Gitbash might be the culprit for not playing nice with other activate commands.

Comment: This exactly solved my problem. I think this is very correct way in Windows OS.

Answer (score 4):

For windows, type "C:\Users\Sid\venv\FirstProject\Scripts\activate" in the terminal without quotes. Simply give the location of your Scripts folder in your project. So, the command will be location_of_the_Scripts_Folder\activate.[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Just open the folder with any gitbash console.**

for example using visualCode and Gitbash console program:

1. Install Gitbash for windows ([there](https://gitforwindows.org/))
2. using gitbash console directly, right click over the project  **open git bash Here** option .

or in Visualcode, looking for a Select->**default shell** and change it for Gitbash

4. now your project is open with bash console and right path, put **source ./Scripts/activate**

btw : **.** with  blank space  **source**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Open your powershell as admin
2. Enter "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force
3. Run "gpedit.msc" and go to >Administrative Templates>Windows Components>Windows Powershell
4. Look for "Activate scripts execution" and set it on "Activated"
5. Set execution directive to "Allow All"
6. Apply
7. Refresh your env

Answer (score 4):

if you already cd your project type only in windows 10

```
Scripts/activate
```

That works for me:)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using:

```
 source ./venv/Scripts/activate
```

Use only:

```
 ./venv/Scripts/activate
```

Your Script will be activated.

Answer (score 3):

A small reminder, but I had my slashes the wrong way on Win10 cmd. According to python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) the activate command is: `C:\> <venv>\Scripts\activate.bat`
When you're browsing directories it's e.g. `cd .env/Scripts`

So to create my venv I used `python -m venv --copies .env` and to activate `.env\Scripts\activate.bat`

Answer (score 3):

For windows Microsoft Tech Support it might be a problem with Execution Policy Settings. To fix it, you should try executing
`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process`

Answer (score 2):

I have a hell of a time using `virtualenv` on windows with git bash, I usually end up specifying the python binary explicitly.

If my environment is in say `.env` I'll call python via `./.env/Scripts/python.exe …`, or in a shebang line `#!./.env/Scripts/python.exe`;

Both assuming your working directory contains your virtualenv (`.env`).

Comment: also, some things don't behave correctly *cough _ansible_ cough* when the virtualenv isn't activated, so if things are weird you may have to activate the venv anyway :(

Answer (score 2):

You can run the source command on cygwin terminal

Answer (score 2):

If you’re using Windows, use the command "venv\Scripts\activate" (without the word source) to activate the virtual environment. If you’re using PowerShell, you might need to capitalize Activate.

Answer (score 2):

Some people are having trouble with vscode i assume as all the above methods dont work.

Its simply because by default vscode uses powershell not cmd...
click on the little arrow beside it and select cmd and run the command.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31340784)

Comment: Even though it doesn't provide an answer to the question, it helps users to who come up here with a scenario he mentioned, like me!

Answer (score 1):

**Finally Worked on Windows 10** by using:

```
activate myvenv
```

where `myvenv` is the name the virtual environment I want to activate.

**So basically, the command is:**

```
activate <<your_venv_name>>
```

All the best!

Comment: not working here, you probably have prerequisites installed that you dont mention here.

Answer (score 1):

if `.\venv\Scripts\activate` does not work neither and you find this error

`\Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system`

you can simple type `set-executionpolicy remotesigned` in powershell and the error must be gone.

> powershell should run as administrator

Answer (score 0):

If you see the 5 folders (`Include`,`Lib`,`Scripts`,`tcl`,`pip-selfcheck`) after using the `virtualenv yourenvname` command, change directory to `Scripts` folder in the cmd itself and simply use "*activate*" command.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is, using backward slahes and using .bat at the end of activate

```
C:\Users>your_env_name\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

If wants to open virtual environment on Windows then just remember one thing on giving path use backwards slash not forward.

This is right:

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\htmldemo\python-virtual-environment>env\Scripts\activate
```

This is wrong:

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\htmldemo\python-virtual-environment>env/Scripts/activate
```

Answer (score 0):

The steps for activating virtualenv using Python3 on windows are:

1. python3 -m venv env
2. .\env\bin\activate

Answer (score 0):

Use These it worked for me`env\Scripts\activate`

Answer (score 0):

For those of you crazy enough to have a custom **DOS** prompt, venv activation may fail, depending on your `%PROMPT%` environment variable content.

Say you have a DOS prompt defined as follows:

```
set PROMPT=$_$E[1;30;40m[$E[0;36;40m%computername% | %userdomain%\%username%$E[1;30;40m] $E[0;33;40m$M$_$E[35;40m$d$s$t$h$h$h$h$h$h$_$E[1;33;40m$p$_$E[1;30;40m$g $E[0;37;40m
```

(btw, it shows as follows, with some fancy colors:

```
[W10-MY_COMPUTER | W10-MY_COMPUTER\JOHNDOE]
15/09/2022 20:31
F:\
> echo "Hello World"
Hello World

[W10-MY_COMPUTER | W10-MY_COMPUTER\JOHNDOE]
15/09/2022 20:31
F:\
>
```

)

Then if you try to activate a venv :

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

it may fail with a rather unclear error that states:

```
Path not found
```

without further indications.

The trick is that `activate.bat`(/`deactivate.bat`) scripts try to save(/restore) the `%PROMPT%` variable with this syntax:

```
...
set _OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT=%PROMPT%
...
set PROMPT=(venv) %PROMPT%
...
```

It can be fixed with this syntax:

```
...
set "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT=%PROMPT%"
...
set "PROMPT=(venv) %PROMPT%"
...
```

now it shows:

```
[W10-MY_COMPUTER | W10-MY_COMPUTER\JOHNDOE]
15/09/2022 20:31
F:\
> venv\Scripts\activate.bat


(venv)
[W10-MY_COMPUTER | W10-MY_COMPUTER\JOHNDOE]
15/09/2022 20:31
F:\
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error in Visual Studio Code as execution policy from Microsoft does not allow to run scripts.
open

> Windows powershell as administrator as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921188/issue-with-virtualenv-cannot-activate)
> then write command

```
 Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process
```

press A to yess for All.
This works for me

Answer (score 0):

I just changed my launcher from `powershell` to `cmd` and it works for me and Virtual Environment created

Answer (score 0):

**For W11**

> source .venv/Scripts/activate

Answer (score -1):

If you are using windows OS then in Gitbash terminal use the following command $source venv/Scripts/activate. This will help you to enter the virtual environment.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open your project using VS code editor .
2. Change the default shell in vs code terminal to git bash.
3. now your project is open with bash console and right path, put 
   "source venv\Scripts\activate" in Windows

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to your virtualenv folder eg `..\project1_env>`
Then type

> `source scripts/activate`

eg `..\project1_env>source scripts/activate`

Answer (score -1):

```
:: location of bat file
::C:\Users\gaojia\Dropbox\Projects\free_return\venv\Scripts\activate.bat 
:: location of the cmd bat file and the ipython notebook
::C:\Users\gaojia\Dropbox\Projects\free_return\scripts\pre_analysis
source ..\..\venv\Scripts\activate
PAUSE
jupyter nbconvert --to html --execute consumer_response_DID.ipynb
PAUSE
```

Above is my bat file through which I try to execute an ipython notebook. But the cmd window gives me nothing and shut down instantly, any suggestion why would this happen?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using windows, just run .\Scripts\activate. Mind that the backslash plays the trick!

Answer (score -2):

It's been a while without usign Django, so when I got back to my old project I run into the same issue on Windows 10
and this worked for me:

> venv/Scripts/activate

Answer (score -2):

Open powershell as admin and paste this "set-executionpolicy remotesigned", then go back to where you tried to run the activate of the venv and it should work :)

Link to the article that explains more in detail:
https://www.stanleyulili.com/powershell/solution-to-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system-error-on-powershell/