# 'virtualenv' won't activate on Windows

Tags: python, virtualenv

Essentially I cannot seem to activate my virtualenv environment which I create.

I'm doing this inside of Windows PowerShell through using

```
scripts\activate
```

but I get an error message:

> "cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this
> system".

Could this be because I don't carry administrator privileges on my computer?

Comment: According to [Microsoft Tech Support](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/964636ad-347e-4b23-8f7a-f36a558115dd/error-file-cannot-be-loaded-because-the-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system), setting Execution Policy to unrestrictred should help. How to do that:
`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force`

Comment: @Kamiccolo AWESOME! You nailed it. Thanks for you help. Great first experience for me on stackoverflow. Thankyou!

Comment: Or, if you have git bash (or mingw) installed, you could just activate it there instead in command windows powershell/command prompt

Comment: @Kamiccolo this worked for me on Windows 7 running Python 3. Thanks!

Comment: @MonaJalal With Python3 you should use built-in `venv` which doesn't have this issue at all.

Comment: If you don't mind, running this in the classical shell cmd.exe works without any hazzle.

Answer (score 340, accepted):

[According to Microsoft Tech Support](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/964636ad-347e-4b23-8f7a-f36a558115dd/error-file-cannot-be-loaded-because-the-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system) it might be a problem with Execution Policy Settings. To fix it, you should try executing `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process` (as mentioned in the comment section by @wtsiamruk) in your PowerShell window. This would allow running virtualenv in the current PowerShell session.

There is also another approach that is more unsafe, but recommended by MS Tech Support. This approach would be to use `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force` (which do unleash powers to screw Your system up). However, before you use this unsafe way, be sure to check what your current ExecutionPolicy setting is by using `get-ExecutionPolicy`. Then, when you are done, you can revert back to this ExecutionPolicy by using `Set-ExecutionPolicy %the value the get-ExecutionPolicy command gave you% -Force`.

Comment: (for new readers) Also make sure you use Scripts\Activate.PS1

Comment: This worked for me. Wanted to point out that I tried the directions in the embed at this link unsuccessfully: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#activate-script. I wonder if its just wrong or is there a difference somewhere.

Comment: Or Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser to use a non-administrative PowerShell.

Comment: most safe aproach is probably to run "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process", that would allow you to run virtualenv in current powershell session

Comment: I really think @wtsiamruk's comment should be selected as the answer. Consindering opening up your Windows for all scripts could be a serious security flaw.

Comment: updated the original answer. Thanks for the heads up and sorry for taking too long ;)

Comment: Is there any way to do this permanently? Every new powershell I open I have to lookup this command to get started.

Comment: @Meekohi I was also looking for this info. You can use `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser` to allow running of all scripts, but it is a security risk... the available options are listed here under the `-Scope` section. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.1#parameters

Comment: If `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process` works for you I think you should also run `Set-ExecutionPolicy Default -Scope Process` after activating the environment to change the execution policy back to avoid any potential issues

Answer (score 70):

In PowerShell use

```
Scripts\activate.ps1
```

instead of *activate.bat* which doesn't work in PowerShell any more.

Also deactivate it by just typing

```
deactivate
```

at the command prompt.

Comment: This is the best way to do it when you don't have any admin previlages. Life saver. thanks Matt

Comment: got the same error. Scripts\Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.

Comment: Works without admin privileges. It's insanely frustrating though.

Comment: This doesn't work since it gives me the error described by the OP.

Answer (score 46):

On Windows, open Windows PowerShell as Administrator

[image]

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
```

Create a virtual environment:

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv foo
cd .\foo
.\Scripts\activate
```

[image]

Answer (score 35):

Open another PowerShell window as administrator and then type:

`set-executionpolicy remotesigned`

Then press <kbd>Y</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now close this PowerShell window and go back to the shell you were working with. This will solve the issue.

Comment: Please explain a bit what this does

Answer (score 13):

Set the excution policy for the *process scope*. After Yes [y], type the script/activate:

[image]

Comment: This seems like the most reasonable and least intrusive answer so far.  Could you explain a bit how it works/what it does?

Answer (score 8):

Another quick solution I have found here (it is applicable for Windows PowerShell only) is like this:

First run

```
Scripts\cmd
```

Then run

```
Scripts\activate.bat
```

At this position, your **Virtualenv** is activated. Now if you deactivate it and want to activate it again later in the same session of PowerShell, you just need to run:

```
Scripts\activate
```

There isn't any need to use **cmd** or **activate.bat** command later.

Comment: There is no `Scripts\cmd` for me.

Answer (score 6):

Below steps are working:

1. Set python path like `C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\` in Environment Variable
2. Open PowerShell in Admin mode , and execute the below command:
   `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force`
3. Close PowerShell and repoen in Admin mode
4. Execute the below command:
   `venv\scripts\activate`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

To activate a Python virtual environment in Visual Studio Code's PowerShell terminal without needing administrator rights, navigate to the script's directory and execute::

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -command .\Activate.ps1 -Scope CurrentUser
```

Then, use the activate command. This approach temporarily permits running the specified script for the current user only.

Note: This will only allow that specific script to run, and only by the user you are currently signed in with.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps to the letter.

Step 1. Use Windows PowerShell as ADMINISTRATOR. (VERY IMPORTANT) and cd into the project folder. Run

```
virtual env
```

Step 2. Check in the scripts folder if you have your *activate.bat* file

```
\env\Scripts\activate.bat # It has to be there.
```

Step 3. If it is not, here make sure you have an Internet connection and run this again

```
virtual env
```

step 4. If the *activate.bat* file is there in the script folder, proceed.

step 5. Run this in your shell:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
```

Step 6. To activate virtualenv on Windows, activate script is in the Scripts folder:

```
env\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Step 7. Check for the (env) at the start of each line. This shows you are on the virtual environment.

Step 8. To reactivate when you come back to the project the second time, run:

```
.\\env\Scripts\activate
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your computer's execution policy on Windows like I do, you can use a Windows command prompt instead of Windows PowerShell and just need to run

```
`Scripts\activate`
```

to activate your environment.

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's problem because that's what the OP was originally trying...

Comment: @Joel Uhm,  cmd and powershell are two different environments. the execution rights that is limited in powershell doesn't get the same restriction when being used in cmd prompts. well at least for this "scripts\activate"

Comment: This worked for me.  You can also go straight into the cmd environment from Powershell just by typing "cmd".

Answer (score 1):

If the machine 64 bit, open the **x86** instance of PowerShell as **Administrator** and check (set) the execution policy.

Try this

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

or

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the directory for that venv you created. And create a new one using the command:

```
python -m venv myvenv
```

Then see if the activate command works.

Answer (score 1):

Search PowerShell
Right click on Windows PowerShell and Run as administrator.

Put below command and hit enter.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
```

Restart you system and try to activate python virtual environment.

if your virtual environment was created successfully then it's should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `windows cmd` instead of the `bash shell` of Pycharm or VS code then it works.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you should activate the virtual environment by the following command in cmd

> E:\your_environment\Scripts> activate.bat

If the **environment is activated** then it shows your environment name enclosed with a bracket like this:

> **(your_environment)** E:\your_environment\Scripts>

Also we can ensure by checking with **where.exe** it will list our active Python environment with order of hierarchy

```
 (your_environment) E:\your_environment\Scripts>where.exe python

 E:\your_environment\Scripts\python.exe

 C:\Python27\python.exe
```

If you need to **deactivate** then do:

> (your_environment) E:\your_environment\Scripts>deactivate.bat

Comment: OP explicitly mentioned PowerShell, not CMD.

Answer (score 0):

To install a **virtual environment** in Windows PowerShell only, but to activate, you'll need to run Windows **PowerShell** as an **Administrator**:

1. `pip install virtualenv`
2. `virtualenv %Name of virtual environment%`

It is installed now to activate it. **Run PowerShell in as an administrator**

3. Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
4. `.\env\Scripts\activate`

To deactivate the environment

5. `.\env\Scripts\deactivate`

For more help, do visit the official page:
https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/1.8.2/

Answer (score 0):

For me on Windows 10 64 bit:

- Open cmd as an Administrator
- `powershell`
- Type `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force`

Voilà, reopen Visual Studio Code and start pythoninnngg.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers found here, I created a short tutorial for this with screenshots.

- Python 3.7
- Windows 10 64bits
- PowerShell

I hope it can help: *[How to setup Python 3 virtual environment on Windows 10](https://github.com/harrywang/self-contained-project/wiki/How-to-setup-Python-3-virtual-environment-on-Windows-10)*

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\path> Set-ExecutionPolicy - Scope CurrentUser
```

> cmdlet Set-ExecutionPolicy at command pipeline position 1
> Supply values for the following parameters:
> ExecutionPolicy: Unrestricted

```
C:\path> Scripts\activate.ps1
```

(new env)

```
C:\path> deactivate

C:\path>
```

This *worked*.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows PowerShell the ExecutionPolicy is set to 'restricted' by default.
This does not allow scripts to be run in PowerShell.

We can only run scripts when the ExecutionPolicy is set to 'RemoteSensing' from 'Restricted'
You can follow the video *"[PowerShell 08 - Changing the execution policy so you can run scripts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2uLUuq0Ft4)"* to do that!

After the above step, you can directly type "Scrits/activate" (while being in the directory of the virtual environment that you want to activate) to activate the virtual environment that you wish to activate!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tffrH.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you have used `pipenv` in creating your virtual environment, you should run `pipenv shell` before executing any command in the Visual Studio Code terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem, The issue was

The possible reason was `venv` doesnot run without "Run as administrator" on powercell
You can run `venv\Scripts\activate` on command prompt instead of powercell

Answer (score 0):

Create a .bat script:

```
call .\env\Scripts\deactivate
RMDIR /Q/S env

call python -m pip uninstall pip -y
call python -m ensurepip
call python -m pip install --upgrade pip
call python -m pip install --user virtualenv
call python -m virtualenv env

call .\env\Scripts\activate

# Install pip requirements
call python -m pip install --upgrade pip
call python -m pip install Pillow

# Run main scripts here
call python main.py

call .\env\Scripts\deactivate
```

Run this script via Command Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by executing this command
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force

Answer (score 0):

. env/scripts/activate here is how to activate the virtual environment using git bash