# How can I activate VENV for Python in Visual Studio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, python-venv

Just trying to follow [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/mzpQgMNdR0g?list=PLlrxD0HtieHhS8VzuMCfQD4uJ9yne1mE6&t=315) and I've crashed and burned 5 minutes in. I can't seem to get the green (venv) preface in Terminal to turn up - and when I call 'activate.ps1' I'm just getting a text file popping up.

I should be seeing this...
[image]
...but no luck!

As you can tell from the tutorial I'm following, I'm a total Python newbie (though I have some decent c# experience). Any help is much appreciated!

[image: py]

Comment: It looks like your machine is configured to open the ps1 file for editing rather than executing it as a command.

Comment: Huh. Weird. Okay, I'll look into that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate
```

to activate the virtual environment

Comment: And also, make sure you have made the virtual environment with python. Look at this link if you need help https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: Hey @FishingCode - Typing 'activate' gets me the (venv) preface in the terminal, but I'm still missing the ('venv' : venv) notification in the status bar of Visual Studio. Also - you wouldn't know how I could make the .ps1 file execute as a command? Thanks so much for your help so far!

Comment: @ReverendSpeed maybe check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713086/virtualenv-wont-activate-on-windows) .Talks about activate.ps1 and how to use it as an executable

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue today.

For Windows, it worked with:

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate
```

And for Mac:

```
. venv/bin/activate

or

source venv/bin/activate
```