# Python Virtual Environment working in Command Prompt, but not in Powershell

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, command-prompt

[image: Picture of the virtual environment working in Command Prompt, and not working in Powershell with the error]
I've been trying to get this virtual environment to work with powershell, but I keep getting this error. The virtual environment works in Command Prompt, but not in Powershell, so I've been wondering what I can do to fix that.

Comment: Please (also) post your code, data, error messages as _text_, [not (just) as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375).

Answer (score 4):

There are three (3) "activate" scripts in the venv scripts directory.

```
PS C:\venv\py39\Scripts> (Get-ChildItem -Filter 'act*').Name
activate
activate.bat
Activate.ps1
```

These are used in the following shells.

```
activate        # bash
activate.bat    # cmd.exe
Activate.ps1    # powershell.exe or pwsh.exe
```

Use the following for PowerShell.

```
.\Activate.ps1
```

The Activate.ps1 script includes a `deactivate` function. Therefore, no `deactivate.ps1` script is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Primary issue is that PowerShell - as you can see on your screenshot - doesn't load commands from the current location by default. Just as it suggests you, try to use `.\activate` instead of `activate`.

But that also might not help and lead to other issue connected to the `Execution Policies`. The command throws some security exceptions after trying to activate the virtual environment. And as it is completly different thing and in order to not duplicate answers, I will redirect you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713086/virtualenv-wont-activate-on-windows) thread which should help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I have gotten that error, instead of `activate`, try `.\activate.ps1`

Comment: Good point, but it isn't just _sometimes_: In order to execute a script located in the _current directory_, PowerShell _always_ requires you to explicitly prefix the script name with `.\ ` (or `./`).