# python virtualenv not activated on windows 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-venv

Im using python 10 and windows-11
i try to activate venv with the following command

```
.\onlineShop\Scripts\activate.bat
```

I create venv using following command

```
python -m venv onlineShop
```

My pip list

```
Package      Version
------------ -------
distlib      0.3.4
filelock     3.6.0
pip          22.0.4
platformdirs 2.5.2
pyaes        1.6.1
Pyrogram     2.0.17
PySocks      1.7.1
setuptools   58.1.0
six          1.16.0
virtualenv   20.14.1
```

also when Im using `.\onlineShop\Scripts\activate` gives me this Error

> "cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system".

> ```
> Problem : venv is not activated
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Microsoft Tech Support, it might be a problem with Execution Policy Settings. To fix it, you should try executing the `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process`

OR IF this problem is not gone Then please read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713086/virtualenv-wont-activate-on-windows#:%7E:text=222,you%25%20%2DForce.)

To activate

```
.\<Virtual-Name>\Scripts\activate
```

or

```
.\<Virtual-Name>\Scripts\activate.bat
```

FOR deactivating `venv`

```
.\<Virtual-Name>\Scripts\deactivate.bat
```

or

```
.\<Virtual-Name>\Scripts\deactivate
```

or

```
deactivate
```

---

If you got this error while activating the virtual Environment:

> cannot be loaded because
> running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
> https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

This means your `Execution Policy is Restricted` SO. To get rid of this error you can run this command.

In Command Prompt:

```
powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

In Powershell:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

#### Replace `<Virtual-Name>` with your virtual environment name

Comment: but how i can deactivate?

Comment: not working for me

Comment: its activated but 
It still does not work for deactivate

Comment: I understand, please add this to your answer to make it more complete---deactivate it by just typing `deactivate`

Comment: yes wiht typing deactivate

Answer (score 2):

Execute following command :

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted CurrentUser
```

If you use this command then you will not face this issue again but if you use below command :

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process
```

Then you need to execute it again and again.