# Why can't i activate my virtual env in cmd?

Tags: python

I created a venv using `"python -m venv env"` and I'm trying to activate it but it kept showing `"The system cannot find the path specified"`

I tried activating using `env\Scripts\activate`
please any idea on  how i can solve this?

i use `python 3.11`, window 11

Comment: Navigate to Scripts folder.    ./activate.ps1.   Or check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713086/virtualenv-wont-activate-on-windows

Comment: @Mark tried navigating to the env but still showing me same problem

Comment: Which operating system? Are you using the CMD shell or powershell?

Comment: I use command prompt

Comment: If you're using the command prompt, then it should be `env\Scripts\activate.bat`

Comment: Provide debugging details, including commands and logs. See [mre].

Comment: @nigh_anxiety Normally `bat` is included in `PATHEXT`, so it shouldn't matter if the suffix (file extension) is typed in.

Comment: Did you create the environment with command prompt in Admin mode or not? This may impact the location of the venv folder and the list of environments available to activate (learned this the hard way). Try running CMD in the same mode as you used to create the environment.

Comment: @iBug Right, it should just work, but being explicit with the `.bat`doesn't hurt anything, and would work around any messed up PATHEXT.  Also, I was clarifying against the previous comment which suggested to  use `activate.ps1`, which won't work directly from the command prompt.