# SyntaxError: invalid syntax when using match case

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I've been trying to use a match case instead of a million IF statements, but anything I try returns the error:

```
    match http_code:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've also tried testing examples I've found, which also return this error, including this one:

```
http_code = "418"

match http_code:
    case "200":
        print("OK")

    case "404":
        print("Not Found")

    case "418":
        print("I'm a teapot")

    case _:
        print("Code not found")
```

I'm aware that match cases are quite new to python, but I'm using 3.10 so I'm not sure why they always return this error.

Comment: Either you aren't actually using 3.10, or you have a problem on a previous line.

Comment: can you crosscheck python version using print (sys.version) inside code

Comment: The code you posted here prints `I'm a teapot` in Python 3.10 for me.

Comment: Just to make it very clear: "9.7" < "10.0". Anaconda doesn't use 3.10 by default yet.

Comment: I have same error on python 3.9.5. Have `match-case` been deprecated on later version of python?

Comment: @Jiwon What do you mean deprecated? This feature was only ***introduced*** in Python 3.10 so of course you'll get an error with 3.9...

Answer (score 38):

The `match`/`case` syntax, otherwise known as Structural Pattern Matching, was only [introduced in Python version 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching). Note well that, following standard conventions, the number after the `.` is **not** a decimal, but a separate "part" of the version number. Python 3.9 (along with 3.8, 3.7 etc.) comes **before** Python 3.10, and **does not** support the syntax. Python 3.11 (and onward) **do** support the syntax.

While it's possible that a syntax error on an earlier line [wouldn't be noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237111) until the `match` keyword, this sort of syntax error is much more a sign that the Python version isn't at least `3.10`.

This code will fail with an assertion if the Python version is too low to support `match`/`case`:

```
import sys
assert sys.version_info >= (3, 10)
```

Or check the version at the command line, by passing `-V` or `--version` to Python. For example, on a system where `python` refers to a 3.8 installation (where it won't work):

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.10
$ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 14 2022, 12:59:47) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

For more details, see [How do I check which version of Python is running my script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322) and [Which version of Python do I have installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917885).

If you're trying to use a virtual environment, make sure that it's activated ([Linux/Mac howto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604699), [Windows (CMD) howto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921188), [Windows (Powershell) howto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713086), [using PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288569)).

In 3.10, the code works:

```py
Python 3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> http_code = "418"
>>> match http_code:
...     case "200":
...         print("OK")
...     case "404":
...         print("Not Found")
...     case "418":
...         print("I'm a teapot")
...     case _:
...         print("Code not found")
   
Out[1]: "I'm a teapot"
```

Comment: In my case this happened: I was using python 3.8 in my virtual environment but in my dockerized project I was using `python:3.8-slim` so docker was not able to compile it successfully as it was not using python3.10. Once I changed image it got resolved. Hope this helps