# Not able to activate virtual environment in cmd

Tags: windows, virtualenv, command-prompt

I have installed virtual environment and also created one called 'Gulpit'. But I am not able to activate it using `source Gulpit/bin/activate`.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1992]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\HP>virtualenv Gulpit
created virtual environment CPython3.11.3.final.0-64 in 934ms
  creator CPython3Windows(dest=C:\Users\HP\GulpIt, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==23.1.2, setuptools==68.0.0, wheel==0.40.0
  activators BashActivator,BatchActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator

C:\Users\HP>source Gulpit/bin/activate
'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with virtualenv - cannot activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921188/issue-with-virtualenv-cannot-activate)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+source+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command

Answer (score 0):

call the bat script for windows

such as

```
C:\Users\HP>Gulpit/bin/Activate.bat
```