# ImportError: No module named selenium in Windows

Tags: python, windows, selenium-webdriver, module

Im learning python. but i have no module named selenium error. here is my code:

````
from selenium import webdriver
  from time import sleep
  
  chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  chromeOptions.add_argument("--incognito")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you get the **error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'**, you could try to manually import it. You should get the exact path of the 'selenium' in your device (for instance, by using the command `pip install selenium`, you should see the following line: *Requirement already satisfied: selenium in c:\users\Name...*). Copy this path and use it in your python script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('paste-here-your-path')
```

Then you can proceed with your code

Comment: like that? https://www.hizliresim.com/m283fd3

Comment: the path is probably much more complex than that, something like  c:\users\NAME\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have installed the selenium module. You can do so by running `pip install selenium` in a system terminal/command prompt

Comment: i did but its didnt worked

Comment: Was there an error or did it say successfully installed?

Comment: Also if you are using a virtual environment and have only installed it globally it won't work. In that case make sure you install it for the virtual environment.

Comment: no https://www.hizliresim.com/3096s19

Comment: how can i do it

Comment: You can follow this to activate your virtual environment if you are using one and then run the pip command once again after you have activated it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921188/issue-with-virtualenv-cannot-activate