# how to activate my virtual environment without having any error

Tags: python-django-storages

venv\Scripts\activate.bat : The module 'venv' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module
venv'.
At line:1 char:1

- venv\Scripts\activate.bat
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (venv\Scripts\activate.bat:String) [], CommandNotFoundExcepti  
  on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule
  ```

Answer (score 0):

-[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8921211/22059436) Here You can check this answer. Similar question asked before. Hope it works.