# How to set system path variables for using nvm on windows if getting error while executing nvm use command

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables, npm-install, nvm

I have successfully installed `nvm` on system and installed nvm version 11.0.0, by `nvm install v11.0.0` but while using `nvm use 11.0.0` or any other version then its showing an error

```
'C:\Users\Vinayak' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

while searching for answers, someone told me that I have to set my system path variables but I dont know how to do it.

please can someone explain me how to get out of this problem step by step

Comment: @Corey sir please can you help me with this problem, i am not getting out of it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61060494/10310278 check out this one

Comment: @VinayakBhardwaj  Did you get fixed this problem?

Comment: @jagath there should not be any space in the command, like in my name "Vinayak Bhardwaj" there was space so command was breaking. Try to install the package at such a place where on executing the command no space is there.

Answer (score 5):

For 'nvm' command to work, you need to make sure the nvm location is set to the PATH environment variable on Windows if not already in place and you run the command under administrator privileges. You can do this via the command line using PowerShell.

- Open the PowerShell window under Administrator privileges 'Run as Administrator'
- Update by appending to the PATH the Environment Variable by running the following command in PowerShell

`$env:Path += "C:\Users\<YOUR_USER_NAME>\AppData\Roaming\nvm"`

- **Important!** Open a new CMD or PowerShell window under Administrator privileges 'Run as Administrator' and type `nvm --version`

[image]