# node and npm cli don't works

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10, nvm

i'm on windows 10 and i try to install node with nvm.
i did exactly the instructions found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61060494/5023851) but only nvm works good.

here is the error message on console
[image: console error message]
and this is the environment variables screen
[image: system environment variables]

i think something is bad in variables but don't know what can i change.

Thank's for your help

Comment: What happens if you type "nvm ls"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage to resolve this by turning nvm on and off:

```
nvm off

nvm on

node -v
```

[image]

FYI, check `ChuckkNorris`'s answer on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/221)