# Debugging node.js with jetbrains variables show 'Collecting data...'

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, pycharm

When debugging a node session and you stop in the debugger, the Variables view shows "Collecting data..." but the data never arrives:

[image: screenshot]

This happens with node version 0.10.34 and 0.10.35 of node.

Comment: For debugging use node 0.10.33 or earlier. See also "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718313/how-to-change-to-an-older-version-of-node-js"

Comment: what IDE version do you work with? Is the problem specific to the code being bebugged, or shows up with each and every variable?

Comment: There are problems with pycharm 3.4 but webstorm 9.0.2 is ok. It seems to be a problem with any variable.

Comment: Please try upgrading PyCharm to v. 4.* - it should include node.js debugger performance fixes available in WebStorm 9.0.2

Comment: Wow! I did not know that there is a pycharm 4 -- when I go "Check for Updates" pycharm 3.4 tells me it is the latest.

Comment: PyCham4 does solve the problem (and it works with my current license). I am still puzzled why I missed that it exists...

Comment: Same Problem here but if i run the process using PhpStorm directly it works

Comment: Switching node version to 0.10.33 fixes the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

I have experienced the same problem with Jet brains once I installed Node v.6.0.0.

The solution was:

1. Install nvm (node version manager).
2. Debug your programs with Node version pointed to v.5.8.0

Comment: I have the same problem with WebStorm and Node v6.0.0. Sadly if you are using ES6 syntax, this can be a problem.

Comment: 58% percent the ES6 syntax is supported also in the 5.11.0 version. See: http://node.green

Comment: But not destructuring. :(

Comment: Any other solution except reverting back to node v5?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrage to 2016.2 and this issue is fixed. Now you can use node 6 with debugging and works perfectly fine.