# node-gyp rebuild build error 'make' failed npm install

Tags: node.js, macos, gruntjs, npm

Getting these errors using npm install on OSX 10.10.5:

```
build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 69
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/4.1.1/bin/node" "/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.8
```

Answer (score 1):

This will resolve by installing Xcode 7. Just run the update on Xcode and, magically, everything works again.

Comment: I had the same issue and it got fixed by accepting the term & agreements of Xcode.

Comment: How about in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for me, installing Xcode 7 didn't fix it. I had to downgrade from node 4.2 to 0.12.7. At this point in time, Mean.js only supports Node 0.10.x. (Note that Node jumps from 0.12.7 to 4.0.)

I use **n** to manage Node versions.
To install **n**

```
$ npm install -g n
```

Then install Node 0.12.7 via **n**

```
$ n 0.12.7
```

Enter n in the terminal to choose Node version.

```
$ n
```

Use arrow to select a version and press enter.

[image]

Then try

```
$ yo meanjs
```

This SO post explains in detail on 
[how to change to an older version of node.js.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718313/how-to-change-to-an-older-version-of-node-js)

Comment: Changing to 0.12.7 was the only thing that worked for me too.