# Getting started with AngularJS on ubuntu vagrant virtualbox, npm start fails

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ubuntu

I am following the tutorial on

> https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

to get started with AngularJS on my ubuntu vagrant virtualbox.

I believe that I have followed all of the steps, but I can't get `npm start` to work.

I get the following response when running npm start:

```
(test5)vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/vagrant/angular-phonecat$ npm start
> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart /vagrant/angular-phonecat
> npm install


...truncated
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: UNKNOWN, unlink '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/connect/History.md'
npm ERR! error rolling back  karma@0.12.37 { [Error: UNKNOWN, unlink '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/connect/History.md']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -1,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'UNKNOWN',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/connect/History.md' }
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/lodash/index.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-65-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /vagrant/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/lodash/index.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/colors/lib/custom/trap.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-65-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /vagrant/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/colors/lib/custom/trap.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/colors/lib/custom/trap.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chmod
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache/-/lru-cache-2.2.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache/-/lru-cache-2.2.4.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/-/mime-1.2.11.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist/-/optimist-0.3.7.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/-/mime-1.2.11.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ent/-/ent-0.0.7.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist/-/optimist-0.3.7.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/utile
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/utile
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/utile/-/utile-0.2.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/utile/-/utile-0.2.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo/-/pkginfo-0.3.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo/-/pkginfo-0.3.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver/2.47.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasminewd/1.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minijasminenode/1.1.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasminewd2/0.0.6
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine/2.3.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/saucelabs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/adm-zip/0.4.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/q/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map-support
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/html-entities
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/accessibility-developer-tools
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver/2.47.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minijasminenode/1.1.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasminewd/1.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasminewd2/0.0.6
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine/2.3.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/adm-zip/0.4.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/q/1.0.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map-support
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/html-entities
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/saucelabs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/accessibility-developer-tools
npm WARN engine selenium-webdriver@2.47.0: wanted: {"node":">= 0.12.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/exit
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-core
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/https-proxy-agent
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/exit
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ent/-/ent-0.0.7.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-core
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/https-proxy-agent
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/agent-base
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/extend
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/extend
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/agent-base
npm ERR! EEXIST, mkdir '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/lodash'
File exists: /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/lodash
Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-65-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /vagrant/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/lodash
npm ERR! fstream_path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/lodash/LICENSE.txt
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:171:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map/0.1.32
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: UNKNOWN, unlink '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/adm-zip/methods/deflater.js'
npm ERR! error rolling back  protractor@2.5.1 { [Error: UNKNOWN, unlink '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/adm-zip/methods/deflater.js']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -1,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'UNKNOWN',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/adm-zip/methods/deflater.js' }
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/request/lib/redirect.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-65-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /vagrant/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/request/lib/redirect.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/request/lib/redirect.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map/0.1.32
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/accessibility-developer-tools/src/audits/FocusableElementNotVisibleAndNotAriaHidden.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-65-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /vagrant/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/accessibility-developer-tools/src/audits/FocusableElementNotVisibleAndNotAriaHidden.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/optimist/node_modules/minimist/test/bool.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-65-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /vagrant/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/optimist/node_modules/minimist/test/bool.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/optimist/node_modules/minimist/test/bool.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chmod
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, utime '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/optimist/node_modules/wordwrap/test/wrap.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-65-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /vagrant/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/optimist/node_modules/wordwrap/test/wrap.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/optimist/node_modules/wordwrap/test/wrap.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call utimes
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! EEXIST, mkdir '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core'
File exists: /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core
Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-65-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /vagrant/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core
npm ERR! fstream_path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:171:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/i
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/i
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/i/-/i-0.3.3.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal/-/deep-equal-1.0.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.5.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp/-/ncp-0.4.2.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.2.10.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/i/-/i-0.3.3.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/0.7.1
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal/-/deep-equal-1.0.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/-/mkdirp-0.5.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp/-/ncp-0.4.2.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/async/-/async-0.2.10.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/0.7.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/0.0.8
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/0.0.8
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/-/minimist-0.0.8.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/-/minimist-0.0.8.tgz
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/http-server/node_modules/ecstatic/node_modules/optimist/node_modules/wordwrap/example'
npm ERR! error rolling back  ecstatic@0.4.13 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/http-server/node_modules/ecstatic/node_modules/optimist/node_modules/wordwrap/example']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/http-server/node_modules/ecstatic/node_modules/optimist/node_modules/wordwrap/example' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vagrant/angular-phonecat/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
npm ERR! weird error 255
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

What is wrong?

I have run `apt-get install nodejs-legacy npm`

I have the following version:

(test5)vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/vagrant/angular-phonecat$ nodejs --version
v0.10.25
(test5)vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/vagrant/angular-phonecat$ npm --version1.3.10

The guide indicates that I should have Node.js v0.10.27+, but that seems strange to me as I have followed the guide and have ended up with v0.10.25.

If I need a newer verison of Node.js I would appreciate advice on which file I should download from here:
https://nodejs.org/download/release/v4.2.1/
and also how I should install it once I download it to my vagrant folder.

**EDIT**

Based on the comments Based I installed nvm (liquidweb.com/kb/…) and changed the currently used version to 0.10.27 (stackoverflow.com/questions/7718313/…). I till get errors when I execute npm start.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-32:/vagrant/angular-phonecat$ npm start

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart /vagrant/angular-phonecat
> npm install

...
npm ERR! Error: UNKNOWN, symlink '../shelljs/bin/shjs'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-65-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /vagrant/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.27
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.8
npm ERR! path ../shelljs/bin/shjs
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! errno -1
...
npm ERR! EEXIST, mkdir '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/http-server/node_modules/optimist/example'
File exists: /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/http-server/node_modules/optimist/example
Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-65-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /vagrant/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.27
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.8
npm ERR! path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/http-server/node_modules/optimist/example
npm ERR! fstream_path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/http-server/node_modules/optimist/example/default_hash.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:171:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/http-server/node_modules/union/examples'
npm ERR! error rolling back  http-server@0.6.1 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/http-server/node_modules/union/examples']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/http-server/node_modules/union/examples' }
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ETXTBSY, unlink '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/connect/History.md'
npm ERR! error rolling back  karma@0.12.37 { [Error: ETXTBSY, unlink '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/connect/History.md']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 62,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ETXTBSY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/connect/History.md' }
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/optimist/example/reflect.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-65-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /vagrant/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.27
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.8
npm ERR! path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/optimist/example/reflect.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/optimist/example/reflect.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/useragent/features/index.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-65-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /vagrant/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.27
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.8
npm ERR! path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/useragent/features/index.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/useragent/features/index.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chmod
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! EEXIST, mkdir '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/source-map/build'
File exists: /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/source-map/build
Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-65-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /vagrant/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.27
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.8
npm ERR! path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/source-map/build
npm ERR! fstream_path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/source-map/build/suffix-source-map.jsm
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:171:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/colors/lib/custom/trap.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-65-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /vagrant/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.27
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.8
npm ERR! path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/colors/lib/custom/trap.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/karma/node_modules/colors/lib/custom/trap.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
...
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ETXTBSY, unlink '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.compat.js'
npm ERR! error rolling back  protractor@2.5.1 { [Error: ETXTBSY, unlink '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.compat.js']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 62,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ETXTBSY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.compat.js' }
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/accessibility-developer-tools/src/audits/UnfocusableElementsWithOnClick.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-65-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /vagrant/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.27
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.8
npm ERR! path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/accessibility-developer-tools/src/audits/UnfocusableElementsWithOnClick.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/accessibility-developer-tools/src/audits/UnfocusableElementsWithOnClick.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chmod
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ETXTBSY, unlink '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/minimatch.js'
npm ERR! error rolling back  glob@3.2.11 { [Error: ETXTBSY, unlink '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/minimatch.js']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 62,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ETXTBSY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/minimatch.js' }
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ETXTBSY, unlink '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js'
npm ERR! error rolling back  jasmine@2.3.2 { [Error: ETXTBSY, unlink '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 62,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ETXTBSY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/vagrant/angular-phonecat/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js' }
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vagrant/angular-phonecat/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

npm ERR! angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart: `npm install`
npm ERR! Exit status 255
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm install
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-phonecat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-65-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/bin/node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.27/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! cwd /vagrant/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.27
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vagrant/angular-phonecat/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

How can this error be solved?

Comment: Its very unlikely that the difference in version is causing this problem, its not even an entire minor version difference. I'd suggest running the newer version of node, the core modules hadn't really change.

Comment: The package for ubuntu is also a little weird. I'd just install using nvm or just copying the contents of the official nodejs tarball into your $PATH. This could be your issue. It looks like its possible that some of these modules are trying to create symlinks. Perhaps try copying the nodejs install to a $PATH that you have write access to via you default vagrant user.

Comment: Ubuntu installs nodejs with the file name `nodejs` where as some modules(assuming shellJS is one of them) expects there to be a command `node`. So you're problem could likely be with the weird way ubuntu installs node through apt.

Comment: Based on your suggestions I installed nvm (http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-nvm-node-version-manager-for-node-js-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) and changed the currently used version to 0.10.27 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718313/how-to-change-to-an-older-version-of-node-js). I till get errors when I execute npm start. Please see the output in my edit.

Comment: Could you give me the output for `npm install`?

Comment: @tsturlz: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1o0e4mu7in28ai4/output%20npm%20install.txt?dl=0

Comment: Try forking this github project https://github.com/dgapitts/vagrant-nodejs-angularjs-tutorial

Comment: @tsuturzl: Cloning went fine. Thanks! But I can't find the shared files on my columer. Cloning got me the following file sustem .vagrant, bashrc.append.txt, provision.sh, README.md, VagrantFile. Earlier when I have gotten vagrant machines I have gotten a vagrant folder, but not this time. The tutorial says it can access the files from project/vagrant-nodejs, but I think I can't

Comment: @tsuturzl: I still get errors when trying to run npm install or npm start: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h9noixpzyu22rwz/output%20npm%20install%202.txt?dl=0 Could the reason be that I am running these commands from Gtit bash?

Comment: Git Bash for windows? I don't think that's the problem. Looks like these modules are trying to create/access symlinks and failing. I was assuming it was a problem with your environment, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Its possible that some of these modules, like karma need to be installed globally. `npm start` is attempting to install dependencies so it runs `npm install` first, and this is where the problem is.

Comment: Are you cloning the repo to a folder on your windows host? If so, perhaps the symlinks(or whatever they're called for windows) are getting created for your windows environment, and aren't compatible in our linux VM. That repo I suggested should clone the project to `/home/vagrant`. Have you tried cloning and running it in the VM, rather than cloning it on the host OS and then mounting it in your VM?