# Cannot debug Nodejs with node-inspector - Websocket_closed

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-debugger

I know that these are some similar / duplicate responses when searching for a solution to this. But the Node world seems to update so regularly that any answers I've found are refering to a much older version.

I'm currently running:

- Node v6.9.1
- Node Inspector v0.12.8

The error I get is as follows:

> Detached from the target
>
> Remote debuggng has been terminated with reason: websocket_closed
>
> please re-attach to the new target

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Comment: Why use `node-inspector` when the version of node you're using has a built-in V8 inspector? Just do `node --inspect --debug-brk foo.js`.

Comment: @mscdex - Thanks, I'm now trying this approach. Is this considered the norm? Using the core debugger now?

Comment: Well, it's certainly handier (being built-in) and being maintained by the V8 team.

Answer (score 0):

I had an identical issue.  After digging around on some forums, I found that downgrading to Node v6.3.1.  [Here](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/907#issuecomment-241175833)

So the next question was "How do I manage versions of node".  Plenty of results show up with nvm.  Stack Overflow has a post on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718313/how-to-change-to-an-older-version-of-node-js).

None of the version managers for windows are kept up with.  I found another one that is kept up to date (as of 1/1/17).  I posted that answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718313/how-to-change-to-an-older-version-of-node-js/41486014#answer-41486014)

Back to the original problem, with the nvm-windows installed:

```
nvm install v6.3.1 //I was running 6.9.1 - downgrade
```

The utility downgrades your npm version

```
Downloading npm version 3.10.3....complete
Installing npm v3.10.3
```

Then use it

```
nvm use 6.3.1
```

**Note** - I use a bunch of IDEs / Editors (depending on what I am doing).  Editors such as Atom or WebStorm which have a Terminal / Command prompt embeded in it will need to be restarted AFTER you install nvm-windows in order to get access to the environment command "nvm".

Once you have node downgraded, the node-inspector worked find for me:

```
node-debug server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe node with higher version(6.9.1) built in inspect, and `node-inspect` don't update longer..

**solution**:use `node --inspect yourapp` replace `node-inspect & node --debug yourapp`
It worked for me.

you can see Github issues [Detached from the target, websocket_closed, cannot read property ref of undefined (NM[0] is undefined)](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/907)