# Heroku: Error 9 when using 'heroku local web' with the Node.js starter project

Tags: heroku, npm

I'm following the "Getting Started on Heroku with Node.js" tutorial, and I got to the part where I use "heroku local web" to launch my app.  When I try, I get this error message:

[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
08:54:38 web.1

|  (node:4716) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please
use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk` instead.
08:54:38 web.1

Exited with exit code 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same Error, Seems like the issue is with node version, downgrading Node had fixed the issue.

Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718313/how-to-change-to-an-older-version-of-node-js) to downgrade Node

Comment: I'll give it a shot.  What version did you downgrade to?

Comment: I had used v6.5.0

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with Heroku after upgrading to Node 8.8.1.
It turned out my **Procfile** indeed contained the deprecated --debug param:

```
web: node --debug=5858 index.js
```

I simply changed this to

```
web: node --inspect=5858 index.js
```

And now everything seems to works as expected.

You may be having this issue because like me, you based your project of the [Getting Started with Node on Heroku](https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started) repo, which still uses an older version of Node.