# Switch version of Node.js to 6.11.5 on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, version

I'm using node v8.2.1, but Google Cloud Functions only supports v6.11.5, so I'm looking to switch my node version accordingly (preferably only using npm). How can I do this?

[How to change to an older version of node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718313/how-to-change-to-an-older-version-of-node-js), the most relevant source I found, has dated answers for Windows. Using nvmw doesn't work for me, I get:

```
$- nvmw install 6.11.5
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure are you asking to change nodejs version for Windows or Google cloud

For Windows I'll <s>highly</s> recommend [NVM for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows), but you'll need to try it yourself, I don't know is it because my customize setting on my PC or what it doesn't success on my side

Answer (score 2):

I also recommend you to try [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows). It will let you install multiple node versions and allow to switch between them. But you need to remove all your previous node installations and related directories first. Depends on your machine, in Windows 10 sometimes got some issues (I was having some problems also when first time install it on my Windows 10) but somehow able to fix it and it's worked for me.