# How to uninstall n and all node versions installed by n

Tags: node.js, archlinux, n

I have installed some Node.js versions with the tool [`n`](https://github.com/tj/n). I have uninstalled all Node.js versions using:

```
sudo n prune
```

except the current (activated) version. If I try to unsinstall the current version:

`sudo n rm 6.10.2`

I get the following error.:

> `Error: cannot remove currently active version (node/6.10.2)`.

I can not figure out, how to set the systems (Arch Linux) default Node.js version, which is already installed and was used to install `n`.

If uninstall `n` using:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g n
```

it leaves the current version on my computer.

```
ls /usr/local/n/versions/node/                                                                                                                                                                      
6.10.2/
```

Do I need to manually delete the folder: `/usr/local/n/`? Or, is there an option in `n` to uninstall it and all the Node.js versions installed by `n`, so that I get the setting before I installed `n`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to manually remove Node versions installed by `n` and set the correct Node system version.

```
sudo n prune
sudo npm uninstall -g n
sudo rm -r /usr/local/n
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/node
```

See the following issues for `n` on GitHub:

- [Cant uninstall n and node #327](https://github.com/tj/n/issues/327)
- [Simple command to switch back to the system installation of Node #486](https://github.com/tj/n/issues/486)

Comment: See also [How to uninstall n? #169](https://github.com/tj/n/issues/169)

Comment: This needs to add some context about how to switch back to the system PATH for node, if it's available.  This leaves you with no way to `npm i -g n` if you wanted to reinstall `n`.

Answer (score 3):

There have been some changes in `n`, so I'll provide an updated and longer answer.

First some context. `n` installs by default to `/usr/local`. If that is also the location of the "system" install of node and npm then it is overwritten. The cache of previously downloaded versions is kept in `/usr/local/n`.

Removing cached node versions downloaded by `n`:

- `n prune` removes all but the version matching the active version of node
- since `n` v3.0.0, deleting the active version is allowed using `n rm <version>`
- (but just manually deleting `/usr/local/n` is easy and removes the top folder too!)

Removing installed node and npm and npx et al:

- since `n` v4.1.0, there is `n uninstall`. (You will need to reinstall the system node and npm to keep using them if they were installed to same location and overwritten.)

Uninstalling `n` itself: if you installed it with `npm install n` then you uninstall it with `npm uninstall n`. This does not affect the cached versions of node or the installed version of node, just `n`. (And there is a small catch-22 if just deleted npm by running `n uninstall`!)

Answer (score -1):

I'm on mac OSX, so I'm not sure if this is relevant to your use case or not, but it may help.

It looks like [n](http://github.com/tj/n) may run into issues if you remove the current version, so I suggest that you delete the folder: `/usr/local/n/`

Then try to uninstall 'n'. In my case, running `npm uninstall -g n` did not remove n. Instead, I needed to find the current installation of n by running: `which n`, then removing that folder from my system.

Then, I would suggest that you use [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) instead.
I've found that it's the easiest and most reliable solution that I've found to date.

More specifically, to address your question about how to access the system installation of node, I don't know what OS you are running, but I don't know that there is a *system* node version.

Typically, you have to manually install node. If there were a *system* node version, I would expect that it would become outdated very quickly, considering node, and other tools, typically iterate through changes fairly quickly.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: "It looks like n may run into issues if you remove the current version...". What do you mean? I didn't have removed the current version. In my case `npm uninstall -g n` removed `n` successfully. My question is tagged with **archlinux**, so I use Linux as OS. Archlinux is a rolling release distribution, so I get the newest Node.js, but that's not the question. I just want to remove the current node version from `n`, so that I can afterwards remove `n`.

Answer (score -1):

Run `n-uninstall` to uninstall n as well as the Node.js versions that were installed with it.
`n-uninstall -y` skips the confirmation prompt - use with caution.