# All NPM commands error with TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I've been using `n` to install node for years with no issues. Now on my Big Sur mac, I updated from v14.17.6 to v16. This updated without incident and `node -v` shows "16.13.1".

However afterwards, any npm command I run immediately errors with this:

```
» npm -v
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/socks-proxy-agent/dist/agent.js:114:44)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/socks-proxy-agent/dist/index.js:5:33)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/agent.js:161:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
```

I tried an earlier v16 build (16.9.1) and `n latest` which is currently 17.2.0, and again any npm command immediately errors with the exact same issue. Dropping my node version back to 14.17.6, and `npm` is back to working properly.

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: It appears that this is not a common enough issue for other people to know how to solve it yet. For now I'm just rolling back to v14. Not sure what else to try.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. If v14 circumvents the issue I'll give that a try

Comment: @Jif if you see my answer below, it turns out v14 was still causing problems and I had to nuke everything from orbit and start over.

Answer (score 30):

I had the same issue. Had some older npm installation and when I ran the windows installer it failed.

I did the following:

- use the installer (https://nodejs.org/en/download/) to remove node,npm
- delete from `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache` and nvm folders if available.
- remove `C:\Program Files\node` if available
- remove Environment Variables all settings for NPM and NODE. There are both in user and system wide multiple entries.

Reinstall everything with the installer.

Comment: `%APPDATA%` ＝ `C:/Users/…/AppData/Roaming/`

Answer (score 8):

I may happen, that after deinstallation you have to delete the node_modules directory in the nodejs Installation Directory manually. And after that do the installation.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this by rolling back to version Node.js 14.15.1 (which I had before), running `npm install -g npm`, then updating to Node.js 16, then running `npm install -g npm` again.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you! If anyone knows what the most recent version of Node.js is that doesn't encounter this issue please mention it below.

Answer (score 1):

For windows users:

I gave up on the issue and the next day picked up where I left. I had a node v16 install that didn't work and threw the same error as the one posted here originally. This is what I did:

- I (re-)installed the dependencies
- uninstalled node again (3rd time)
- reinstalled node (16.3.2)
- closed all power shell windows
- opened a new power shell window

Executed node:

```
PS C:\Users\*****> node
Welcome to Node.js v16.13.2.
Type ".help" for more information.
>
(To exit, press Ctrl+C again or Ctrl+D or type .exit)
>
```

Executed npm:

```
PS C:\Users\*****> npm
npm <command>

Usage:

npm install ...

Configuration fields: npm help 7 config

npm@8.1.2 F:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to do the following:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
```

then

```
sudo n 16
```

switch back to node 16, then npm works.

then

```
sudo n rm 18
```

```
sudo n 18
```

to reinstall 18, or delete npm folder again to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that even though most npm commands (`run`, `-v`, etc.) worked, some like `npm publish` were throwing new errors even on 14.17.6. Ultimately what I ended up doing was [nuking n and all versions of node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648514/how-to-uninstall-n-and-all-node-versions-installed-by-n):

```
rm -rf /usr/local/n
```

Then manually installing the latest node version from node.js, and then doing a `npm i -g n` and `n latest`. Now I'm back in a good state, all my npm commands seem to work, and I only have two versions of node instead of the 15 or so I'd accumulated over the years.

Will leave the question unanswered for now in case someone else has a less drastic solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me that install by using standalone zip file, you need to delete these two folders before you made an update.

- node\node_modules\corepack
- node\node_modules\npm

Answer (score 0):

**If you have node installed locally** :

**Context**: We have some admin access restrictions on our machines, which prevents us from running msi's and other installers without approval from IT. So to workaround we use the frontend-maven-plugin to locally install node and npm in our git working directory. The resulting structure is
node-app/
...
node/
node_modules/
dist/
...
/package.json

**Problem**: Sometimes things can get mangled (I suppose I don't understand sufficiently), especially when moving between versions of npm via the maven frontend plugin. The result is errors like the one above, among others.

**Solution (windows-restart-style)**:
The most systematic way to proceed is:

- Close and stop all node-executing applications
- delete 'dist/', 'node/', and 'node_modules'
- re-install node and npm using the maven frontend plugin.

I'm sure this answer is not for everyone, but if you happen do be using frontend-maven-plugin, make sure to give this a try when all else fails.

Answer (score 0):

ahhh, just change the node version (18.16.1) using nvm

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Deleting `node_modules` folder

Then

Firsty:

```bash
npm cache clean --force
```

Secondly:

```bash
npm install
```

Works for me.