# Why do I get a warning about node version?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

When running the newest firebase tools I still get this warning:

Warning: You're using Node.js v8.11.3 but Google Cloud Functions only supports v6.11.5.

Why is that? My understanding is that cloud functions support node 8 if you put

"engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },

in package.json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js version and Google Cloud functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50001512/node-js-version-and-google-cloud-functions)

Comment: It's a warning to let you know that your emulated functions are running with a different version of node than would be used in Cloud Functions.  You can ignore it if you know what you're doing.

Comment: I hope I know what I am doing. I changed package.json according to this blog post: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/cloud-functions-for-firebase-config-node-8-timeout-memory-region.html so I expect that it is OK to run node 8 and that was why I wondered about still getting the warning.