# appcenter-cli can't be installed (command not found)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute, visual-studio-app-center-test

When I do the following, get command not found. For some reason it looks like its referencing 9.11.1 and not 10.11.0 but I'm really not sure what the problem is.

```
$ npm install -g appcenter-cli
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.11.1/bin/appcenter -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.11.1/lib/node_modules/appcenter-cli/bin/appcenter.js
+ appcenter-cli@1.1.5
updated 1 package in 11.82s

$ appcenter
-bash: appcenter: command not found

$ node -v
v10.11.0
```

I've always tried using `sudo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: We've just released a new version with support for node 10.x - please give version `1.1.7` a go and let us know if you hit any issues. [Details of the release are here](http://We%20just%20released%20this:%20appcenter-cli%20released%20with%20node%2010%20support:%20https://github.com/Microsoft/appcenter-cli/releases/tag/v1.1.7%20-%20once%20npm%20cache%20has%20refreshed%20-%20give%20it%20a%20whirl%20and%20let%20us%20know%20if%20it's%20not%20working.)

`appcenter-cli` currently appears to be broken on node 10.x - I would advise [trying an older version of node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718313/how-to-change-to-an-older-version-of-node-js) to see if that allows the cli to install.

We're aware of this issue but node 10.x support for the cli has not yet made it on to our backlog - you could have a bash at adding node 10 support yourself and contribute to [the open source project where this lives](https://github.com/Microsoft/appcenter-cli) :)

Comment: Used nvm to change to 8 and it worked great. Thanks Owen

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for bringing this to our attention. We're planning on proposing this bug fix. As an additional information, could you let us know which CLI command you were planning on using post logging in?

Comment: `appcenter codepush deployment list -a <company>/<appname> --displayKeys` primarily and pushing CodePush updates