# NodeJs downgrade problems

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-7, nvm, downgrade

First i downloaded node version `v10.13.0`, now i need to use older version `8.11.3` so i downgraded the node version referencing to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7718438/10447560). After succesful installation, i modified the `PATH`  as they suggest by adding

> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.11.3

to `System Variable`. I also find out that i have 3 copy of this path

> C:\Program Files\nodejs

in my `System Variable`(one i've added by myself when i downloaded first time the `v10.13.0`-version and the rest 2 have no idea how got there, not sure if it is useful to metion here). After all these i switched to older version and tried to check the node version, then the window pops out with error message `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe Node.exe is not a valid 32-bit application` and the below console output. No related info out there, who could help me out with that ? And by the way,isn't that message should appear if you run `64-bit` application on `32-bit` OS ? That is weird, because i'm using `Win7` `64-bit` OS.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>node -v
v10.13.0

C:\Users\Administrator>npm -v
6.4.1

C:\Users\Administrator>nvm ls

  * 10.13.0 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
    8.11.3

C:\Users\Administrator>nvm use 8.11.3
Now using node v8.11.3 (64-bit)

C:\Users\Administrator>node -v
access denied.

C:\Users\Administrator>npm -v
access denied.
access denied.

C:\Users\Administrator>nvm ls

10.13.0
8.11.3

C:\Users\Administrator>nvm -v

Running version 1.1.7.
```

Comment: This issue might be fixed after re-installing the nvm from scratch, make sure you uninstall the current nvm.

Comment: I've deleted all node,nvm,npm together, and installed the needed version again from scratch(https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.3/). This solved the problem.

Comment: Great! Would you please tag the comment as useful.

Comment: i don't have that arrow here dont know why

Comment: Then please make the answer to the question accepted, so it will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reinstall nvm and then install it from scratch.