# Cannot install node version 8.11.2 into my ubuntu machine

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-18.04

I need to install nodejs version8.11.2 into my ubuntu machine. my ubuntu versions is 18.04.

In my machine installed node version is 10.0. Although I use 'sudo apt-get remove nodejs' command to uninstall nodeJS, it is not removing. When i run node -v, it gives the same version.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu1Px.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu1Px.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change to an older version of Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718313/how-to-change-to-an-older-version-of-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

## Install Node.js from the NodeSource repository

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
```

The command above :

1. Adds the NodeSource signing key to your system.
2. Creates an apt sources repository file.
3. Installs all necessary packages.
4. Refreshes the apt cache.

Then you can do : `sudo apt install nodejs`

---

At the time of writing this `12.4.2` is the current latest Node.js version.
You can install version `10.16.0` by changing `setup_12.x` to `setup_10.x` in the first command.