# I want to use Node 14 to run my project but it always runs on Node 12. How to fix this?

Tags: node.js

[It shows node version 12 but with sudo it shows 14, I want to use version 14 in future, How can i configure it to version 14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Orqlf.png)

Comment: `npm install n -g` , `n stable` , `sudo n stable` n is a node version manager you can add any version name instead of "stable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question will help you understand better.

[How to change to an older version of Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718313/how-to-change-to-an-older-version-of-node-js)

Just use your version instead of the older version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Install NVM and desired versions of Node, after installing them you can choose any Node versions from the installed list and you can change the Node version in which your project wants to run.

In your case after installing nvm and Node 14.xx, try nvm use 14.xx or else your desired version. This will change to Node 14.xx version.

You can install NVM by going through this link https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm
and after that you can install node versions through NVM itself.