# Update the old version of nodejs and npm for Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I'm trying to update the old version of Nodejs and Npm for MacBook.

My current version: Nodejs v16.13.1 , npm 8.1.2

I want to update the old version again: **Nodejs v12.13.0** , **npm 6.14.6.0**

I have researched but still can't update. Hope you can help me.

Comment: use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Comment: Do you need nodejs on your entire os or just to run some application? Are you open to a workaround that requires a couple of lines on the shell before the start of your app?

Comment: @JRichardsz I need it to run on my entire operating system

Comment: Did you try nvm or the method proposed in the answer?

Comment: I'm reading it, but haven't found a solution yet

Comment: @JRichardsz I have successfully updated nodejs version, but npm still not

Comment: After installing nvm, you need to install node versions also. then using "nvm use NODE_VERSION" you can install node version what you want

Answer (score 0):

As stated here, you might want to use "n" a node version manager for UNIX based systems.

[How to change to an older version of Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718313/how-to-change-to-an-older-version-of-node-js)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).