# What if an app(nodejs) is installed paralell with Chocolatey and npm?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, installation, chocolatey

I found that if I issue the command `node -v` in the VisualCode terminal in Windows, I get the following response:

```
v16.14.0
```

However, if I issue the `choco list --localonly` command, this is also included:

```
nodejs-lts 14.18.1
```

So does that mean it's double installed? And which one actually runs on the machine? Can one be removed because it is redundant and won't harm the other installation?

Comment: The one you got when you ran `node -v` (16.14.0) is the one currently being used. You can remove the other one if you wanted to, but the reason why such version management exists is sometimes node projects only work with certain node versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Yes, there are two node binaries (with different versions) on your machine.
- The one you got when you ran `node -v` (16.14.0) is the one currently being used.
- You can remove the other one if you wanted to, but the reason why such version management exists is sometimes node projects only work with certain node versions.

If you are in the future trying to test out your project with a older node version, [another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74064732/7589775) recommended `npx -p node@4.9.0 -- node -v`